# Best method for storing history and updating with changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need help from you design geniuses again!

I'm working on an app that needs to store changes and often recall them as well as detect when they have changed from a file from the customer. The simplest example will be a persons name.

So I have a **Member** model and attached (polymorphically) is the **Identity**. I need to store all changes to the identity so that I can look back and see what someones name was at this or that time for this or that file transfer.

I have a **has_many** relationship from the Member to the Identity currently.

I will be receiving files with the updated information on it. Is there a good way to compare the information to the existing and then add a new record if something is different? Or better yet, have it report back what is different and then I can choose to update or not?

Each time I started to program this it became pretty long and confusing each time and I was hoping there is a better way to do it so I don't need to re-create the wheel, my wheels are usually flat and dented anyway;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) for this. It automatically detects if something has changed when the model is saved, and creates a new "version" of the model in a different table.

Comment: I looked a few gems and got a little nervous. I'm worried that an error could be found in the gem or it could go away and then I'd be back to square one after spending months counting on it. Might be a silly concern on my part though?

Comment: The gem is being actively maintained, so I don't think you should worry about it. I've used it often in the last few years and the only problem I had was when integrating it with carrierwave.